# C# WPF Блокировать операции на время анимации

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Вот такой командой запускаю анимацию:

```
DoubleAnimation animation = new DoubleAnimation(newValue, new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)));
self.BeginAnimation(AnimatedPropertyProperty, animation);
```

Во время анимации в программе я могу совершать другие операции. К примеру, нажать другую кнопку, которая запустит другую анимацию.

Какие есть способы блокировать другие операции или просто на время отключить другие элементы управления в интерфейсе пока не завершится анимация?

Comment: Не завидую пользователям вашей программы, ждать 5 секунд анимации...

Comment: @Андрей На самом деле меньше 1 секунды. :)
Просто поставил так много для проверки.

Answer (score 0):

У `UIElement` есть свойство [IsEnabled](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.uielement.isenabled(v=vs.110).aspx). Установи его в `false` для корневого элемента (хоть для всего окна) и пользователь не сможет с ним взаимодействовать. Убедись, что при любом исходе операции ты вернёшь его обратно в `true`. Например, подписавшись на событие [Completed](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.media.animation.timeline.completed(v=vs.110).aspx) класс `Timeline` и его наследников.

Comment: А при помощи MVVM это как-нибудь можно сделать?

Comment: @Dominik: Нет, анимация — чисто вьюшная вещь. Операциям с ней в VM не место.

Comment: @Dominik любые паттерны нужно применять ради удобства разработки и поддержки продукта. MVVM ради MVVM породит только тонные ненужного кода. С моей точки зрения, правильнее использовать MVVMC и данную логику описать в контроллере.